# "Разрезать" ссылку средствами PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, как разрезать ссылку такого формата

```
https://static.site.com/images/common/galleries/id/with_logo/image.jpg
```

Чтобы получить только параметр **id**

Ссылку получаю из парсера, а параметр в дальнейшем используется для воспроизведения **POST** - запроса через **cURL**. Других способов выдернуть его со страницы я не нашел :)

Comment: для разборка `url` обычно применяют [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php), но тут с ее помощью вы получите только строку целиком `images/....` целиком. Что вы ожидаете как результат тут ? `with_logo`?  регулярки вам в помощь

Comment: Как результат ожидаю `id`. Догадывался, что они мне нужны, но я в них не силён)

Comment: то есть id это некий набор букв-цифр-тире? а не само слово `id` ? _зы: всегда приводите пример реальных данных_

Comment: Да, это только набор цифр

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = 'https://static.site.com/images/common/galleries/id/with_logo/image.jpg';
$str_arr = explode('/', $str);
$id = $str_arr[6];
```

P.s. если это окончательная ссылка, то этот вариант подходит. Иначе лучше прибегать к более умным разборам строки, нежели просто через `explode`

Comment: В целом да, подходит, держал его в мыслях. Просто думал, есть более изящные, что ли, и универсальные способы.

Comment: Вообще, хорошо бы было описать, зачем это и где будет использоваться, в таком случае будет гораздо больше вариантов. `explode` - самое примитивное, что в голову приходит

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Но в целом формат ссылок от страницы к странице не меняется. Так что должно подойтию

Comment: Для парсера это вполне достаточно. Если на сайте-доноре изменятся URL, то нужно будет просто индекс в массиве поменять